# Oracle: cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types?

Tags: oracle, unicode, oracle11g, ssis

I created an `SSIS` package that will copy data between two `Oracle` tables in different databases. The only difference between both tables is the table name; both source and destination tables have the same exact column names, types, etc.

I run the package and I get the following error with every single column:

> [OLE DB Source [1268]] Error: Column "RADIO" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.

In the case of the column `RADIO`, why would I get this error if both columns are `VARCHAR2(180)`?

Both databases are `NLS_CHARACTERSET` set to `WE8MSWIN1252`.

Comment: What is the `nls_characterset` of the source and target database?

Comment: Source is `WE8MSWIN1252` and destination is `AL32UTF8`.

Comment: I changed the destination database to `WE8MSWIN1252` but I still get the same error.

Comment: Is all the data in a Western European language?  Or do you have Eastern European/ Arabic/ Chinese/ Japanese/ etc. characters?  How did you change the character set of the destination database (I'm assuming this is a toy dev database)?

Comment: How did you change the database character set?

Comment: I changed it like this: `ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET INTERNAL_USE WE8MSWIN1252`

Comment: All the data is in a Western European language. It's mostly English with very little Spanish.

Comment: Looks like SSIS doesn't believe one of them is non-unicode.  Check the metadata on each of the transformations, and make sure they line up with what is in the database at the moment.  You can right-click and choose advanced editor and look at the outputs/inputs to see this.  Or, you can right-click on one of the connectors between transformations and choose Edit to see Metadata.